# Python XML Writing Safe to Thread?

Tags: python, xml, multithreading, python-2.7

I have data coming in through sockets, being queued up to be parsed and checked for certain requirements and then passed to my FileWrite() function.

It seems to slow down over time even with a fairly even level of data. I can't seem to find a leak with it or a reason for it to take so long.

This is a snippet of the code. It goes backwards through the list because there's also a quick check it makes to be sure it is worth writing and might pop something out of the list once in a while but I've ran timers without it and it doesn't make a difference.

Snippet:

```
def FileWrite():


    CopiedList = []
    del CopiedList[:]
    CopiedList[:] = []

    CopiedList = list(ListForMatches)

    try:
        if os.path.exists("Temp.xml") == True:
            os.remove("Temp.xml")
        if os.path.exists("Finished.xml") == True:
            os.remove("Finished.xml")

        try:
            if os.path.exists("Temp.xml") == True:
                try:
                    os.remove("Temp.xml")
                except:
                    print "problem removing temp.xml?"

            root = ET.Element("Refunds")
            tree = ET.ElementTree(root)

            for Events in reversed(CopiedList):
                try:

                    XMLdataparse2 = []
                    del XMLdataparse2[:]
                    XMLdataparse2[:] = []
                    XMLdataparse2 = Events.split('-Delimeter_Here-')


                    try:
                        if "Snowboarding" in XMLdataparse2[0]: #Football
                            matches = ET.SubElement(root, "Event", type = XMLdataparse2[0])
                            ET.SubElement(matches, "EventTime").text = str(XMLdataparse2[1])
                            ET.SubElement(matches, "EventName").text = str(XMLdataparse2[2])
                            ET.SubElement(matches, "Location").text = str(XMLdataparse2[3])
                            ET.SubElement(matches, "Distance").text = str(XMLdataparse2[4])
                    except:
                        print "problem preparing XML tree"

                except:
                    agecounter = agecounter - 1 #Prevent infinite loop in case of problem
                    print "Problem moving to next XML tree"

            trry = 0 #Attempts writing the XML file a few times (just in case)
            while trry < 5:
                try:
                    tree.write("Temp.xml")
                    break
                except:
                    trry +=1

        except:
            print "problem writing XML file"
            e = sys.exc_info()[0]
            print e

    #except:
    except WindowsError, e:
        e = sys.exc_info()[0]
        print e

    #Let's get the file ready to go.
    try:

        if os.path.exists("Temp.xml") == True:
            os.rename("Temp.xml","Finished.xml")
    except:
        print "Problem creating Finished.xml"


    return
```

My question is would it be possible to safely pass the parsing by '-Delimeter_Here-' and writing to the XML file to a thread. If I have 200 pieces to add could 200 threads parse that bit of data and safely write them to the same file or is that going to cause all kinds of havoc?

I can't really see another way of removing this bottleneck but I'd appreciate any suggestions or a safe way to thread this.

Update:

So I've been reading around and doing a little testing. Suspicions confirmed it would not be safe to have multiple threads writing into the XML at the same time.

In theory I could thread it to split the list by the delimiters in separate threads which would stop one thread from  having to do that. I don't know how I would write the strings to the XML from those threads though. I don't know how I could add them to another queue without having to just parse them up again anyway.

Maybe a function which will take a set of strings to write to the XML and try this file lock part of the threading library.

So for each result in that last a thread starts by splitting up the data and checking it when passes it into another thread function to write it to the XML locking one at a time.

I'm hoping it's possible to have threads wait until the lock comes off and rotate that way.

**Update**

I wrote it using threading to parse up the strings and file locking to prevent it slowing down. This is the only way I see to speed this up. Having some trouble getting it to update the file properly without parsing the XML constantly which is a bigger slowdown (posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35406927/file-locked-xml-thread-writing-to-new-file)).

I can't think of any other way of speeding this up.

Comment: Have you considered using a memory mapped file with MAP_SHARED set to true? http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap

Comment: "I can't seem to find a leak with it or a reason for it to take so long." Profile your code, you might be fishing in the wrong place. In case it is really the xml processing, you should use xml.etree.cElementTree if you not already use it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, both of you. Padraic I'm currently running on Windows (I know, I know just haven't had to time to port everything over and get comfortable with Linux yet). I've not worked with a profiler before but between just watching the console and running timers I'm fairly sure this is where the slowdown is. I'm using xml.etree.ElementTree... is that different from xml.etree.cElementTree?

Comment: Oh snap just found it. 15-20x faster? I'll give that a go for sure cheers. http://effbot.org/zone/celementtree.htm